# syntax error near unexpected token `if' in Bash Scripting

Tags: bash, scripting

Attempting to locate all lines in a list of files containing `jane`, then test if the result exists as a real file, and append their names to a Document. Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

> oldFiles.txt

janeSearch=$( grep " jane " ../data/list.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 1,3 )    

for x in $janeSearch;
        if test -e ~/$x: then
                echo $x >> oldFiles.txt
        fi
```

Can someone explain why I get the following error?

```
syntax error near unexpected token `if'
```

Comment: Use ; instead of :

Comment: Also, you probably miss a `do` before the `if`.

Comment: Well, excuse my bad syntax, I am new to bash scripting!

Comment: Also a `done` after the `fi` to pair with the missing `do`.

Comment: https://shellcheck.net is a terrific resource for checking syntax errors in shell code. Add it to your development process.

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks, I will definitely remember this when I am coding in bash!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggesting to try the following

#!/bin/bash

```
> oldFiles.txt

janeSearch=$( grep " jane " ../data/list.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 1,3 )    

for x in $janeSearch;
        if (test -e ~/$x); then
                echo $x >> oldFiles.txt
        fi
done
```